# How to get all extra values from intent

Tags: android

Here is my code

```
     Log.i("sdfgsdf", time.toGMTString());
        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        Intent y=  new Intent(SENT);
        y.putExtra("number", phoneNumber);
        y.putExtra("time", time.toString());

        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";
        int FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT =(0x08000000) ;
        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
        y, FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
        new Intent(DELIVERED), FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        //---when the SMS has been sent---
        r=  new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
             public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

                switch (getResultCode())
                {

                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent"+arg1.getStringExtra("number"), 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Constant.DB = Compose.this.openOrCreateDatabase("Indigo",MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                        Constant.DB.execSQL("UPDATE Message SET IsMsgSent='true' where DateAndTime='" + arg1.getStringExtra("time") + "' and ContactNumber='"+arg1.getStringExtra("number")+"'");
                        Constant.DB.execSQL("UPDATE Message SET FolderId='5' where DateAndTime='" + arg1.getStringExtra("time") + "' and ContactNumber='"+arg1.getStringExtra("number")+"'");
                        Constant.DB.close();
                      //  unregisterReceiver(r);
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure"+arg1.getStringExtra("number"), 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Constant.DB = Compose.this.openOrCreateDatabase("Indigo",MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                        Constant.DB.execSQL("UPDATE Message SET IsMsgSent='false' where DateAndTime='" + arg1.getStringExtra("time") + "' and ContactNumber='"+arg1.getStringExtra("number")+"'");
                        Constant.DB.close();
                       // unregisterReceiver(r);
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service"+arg1.getStringExtra("number"), 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Constant.DB = Compose.this.openOrCreateDatabase("Indigo",MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                        Constant.DB.execSQL("UPDATE Message SET IsMsgSent='false' where DateAndTime='" + arg1.getStringExtra("time") + "' and ContactNumber='"+arg1.getStringExtra("number")+"'");
                        Constant.DB.close();
                       // unregisterReceiver(r);
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU"+arg1.getStringExtra("number"), 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Constant.DB = Compose.this.openOrCreateDatabase("Indigo",MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                        Constant.DB.execSQL("UPDATE Message SET IsMsgSent='false' where DateAndTime='" + arg1.getStringExtra("time") + "' and ContactNumber='"+arg1.getStringExtra("number")+"'");
                        Constant.DB.close();
                      //  unregisterReceiver(r);
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off"+arg1.getStringExtra("number"), 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Constant.DB = Compose.this.openOrCreateDatabase("Indigo",MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                        Constant.DB.execSQL("UPDATE Message SET IsMsgSent='false' where DateAndTime='" + arg1.getStringExtra("time") + "' and ContactNumber='"+arg1.getStringExtra("number")+"'");
                        Constant.DB.close();
                      //  unregisterReceiver(r);
                        break;
                }

            }

        };
        registerReceiver(r, new IntentFilter(SENT));

        //---when the SMS has been delivered---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;                        
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));        

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

And when i send multiple sms using a for loop iam getting extras of only last sent sms.how to get all extras..?

Comment: show how you are sending msg using loops and how you are retrieving extras

Comment: retrieving extras in switch case of above (getresultcode) and coming to loop common for loop with some condition..

Comment: To identify the extra for each intent you have to sent different request code while creating different intent.And on in onActivityResult depending on the request code you can identify the extra

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Calling intent place do it like this

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("RetailerName", keyword);
bundle.putString("positon", aString);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

receive intent place get the data like this

```
  Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
  String RetailerName = bundle.getString("retailerName");
```

Answer (score 18):

This should get all values

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
    Object value = bundle.get(key);
    Log.d(TAG, String.format("%s %s (%s)", key,  
    value.toString(), value.getClass().getName()));
}
```

Comment: This is giving me log in this format LocList [] (java.util.ArrayList)

Comment: probably array in array, you should check value is an array or not. if array then you should write another for loop to display it.

Answer (score 1):

In a Receiver

```
Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();
```